# Is it possible there will be an encoding error when reading a character?

Tags: c, input, error-handling, scanf, errno

> If an encoding error happens interpreting wide characters, the function sets errno to EILSEQ.

```
scanf("%d", &i);
```

If the input is more than 2147483648 (if `i` is `signed int`), `scanf` will change `errno`'s value.

But what if I try to read a character, like this:

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

Is it possible to enter a character that causes an encoding error? I've tested it with UTF-8 input, but that worked well (for `௮`, `c`'s decimal code is `-32`, but `errno` is `0`).

Comment: `%c` doesn't do wide characters. `%lc` would be the relevant conversion specifier.

Comment: Your program works entirely as expected. The first character value of your Tamil Unicode character `௮`, U+0BEE, is indeed 224 in UTF8 notation. When interpreted as a *signed* character value, that is the `-32` that you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use a different conversion specifier for wide characters:

```
wchar_t c;
scanf("%lc", &c);
```

The answer to your question is "yes", you should always check that the input is valid!

It may not be practically possible for a user to *type* an invalid character (a keyboard only produces valid characters), but input can come from other sources, and in most cases you can't predict those in advance. It's also possible that the input character set doesn't match what your program thinks it is (in which case you have bigger problems, but a check for invalid encodings will help catch the problem sooner).

In any case, it's good practice to check the return value from `scanf` the same way you check the return value from `malloc` (you *do* do that, right?)

```
if (scanf("%lc", &c) != 1)
  emit_input_error_and_abort();
```

Comment: I do always check the `scanf`'s returned value, and since I know in my program the input is ASCII-only, that's enough for now. However, do you know an example when `check_encoding(); scanf("a character", &c);` would change `errno`'s value?

Comment: I don't know what "check_encoding" does? `scanf` will never fail to read a `%c` non-wide character unless you hit EOF, ENOMEM, or one of the other not-actually-input return codes.

Comment: If `c` is `char`, that function would check the input's encoding. If it's UTF-8, the funcion'd display an error message. Or something like that. :D I only want to know when `errno` is changed. #1: the variable is a number-type, and the input is out of the range. #2: ??? I thought if I enter UTF-8 chars that also causes OoR,  and like in numbers, `scanf` changes `errno`, but no. Any other examples when I must check `errno`?

Comment: You must always check errno when scanf returns any number other than the expected. The value of errno at any other time should be considered undefined, and checking of it changes is not enough in case you have the same error twice.